# Getting local declaration hides instance variable warning message for multiple statements

Tags: iphone

I can't get this code to work.

Declared playpauseButton just above the given below statements

```
UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Getting local declaration of `playpauseButton` hides instance variable warning message for following statements

```
playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playpauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playpauseButton];
```

After i defined `playpauseAction method`

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {    
if( playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateNormal ){
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[audioPlayer play];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}  else if (playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateSelected)
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[audioPlayer pause];
 [self pauseTimer];
 } else if (playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateNormal)
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[audioPlayer play];
[self resumeTimer];}}
```

Some help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you declaring playpauseButton?

Comment: I just added that statement above in my post. Please check it.

Comment: I think you have declared playpauseButton as an instance variable also, so remove UIButton from line UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: After removing UIButton play button is not working at all.If clicking on it nothing is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you that you have two declarations of `playpauseButton`.  One is in the interface section of your class (the instance variable) and the other is a local variable.

It's not an actual error but the warning tells you that you may get results different from what you want.

Comment: How can i get rid of these warnings.

Comment: Give the variables names that are different from each other.

Comment: What do the new warnings say?

Comment: i tried changing it to self.playpauseButton= newplaypauseButton it gives warning in red to replace back to playpauseButton.

Comment: That assignment doesn't seem to match anything in your question.  Go back to the code you posted.  Select `playpauseButton` in the `UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
` line. Click the little triangle at the end of the variable name and choose the option "Edit all in scope". Type a name you don't use anywhere else.  The original warnings should go away.